# How to take user id from the form or database in Django?

Tags: django

I have a simple form login.html in Django. I take username and password from the login form and use to validate in my Django view:

```
def login_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        username1 = ''.join(username)
        password = request.POST['password']
        password = ''.join(password)    
        password1 = hashlib.sha1(password).hexdigest()
        user = authenticate(username=username1, password=password1)
        user_id = request.galaxyuser.id
        if len(user) > 0:
            return render_to_response('right.html', {'user_id':user_id}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            return render_to_response('wrong.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    else:
        return render_to_response('login.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I also want to get the id of the user which I have to use later. I tried using:

```
user_id = request.galaxyuser.id
```

But it returns `None` value. Here's my models.py:

```
class GalaxyUser(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=765)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    external = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    deleted = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    purged = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=765, blank=True)
    form_values_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    disk_usage = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=16, decimal_places=0, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'galaxy_user'
```

**Edit:**
My custom authentication function:

```
def authenticate(username='username', password='password'):
    return GalaxyUser.objects.filter(username=username, password=password)
```

Comment: Based on your comments to Tomita, you appear to have a completely bizarre understanding of how database queries work. As he stated, *you need to use `get`*. That will return *one matching instance*.

Comment: Plus, you should not be doing the hashing in your login function, but pass the unhashed password into authenticate and do the hashing there.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what `request.galaxyuser` is supposed to be, but given a user object, the id is an attribute of that object. The `authenticate` function is supposed to return a User object if the credentials are valid.

```
user = authenticate(username=username1, password=password1)
user_id = request.galaxyuser.id  # what are you doing here?

user_id = user.id  # this is the user ID.
```

This question might have different answers depending on how you implemented your custom `User` class. I'm assuming it's the class returned by `authenticate`.

#### Update:

Your example shows you returning a `QuerySet` (a `.filter`) which is a list of rows.

You need to either return one object so that you can do look up the ID attribute, or you need to modify the view to account for this strange behavior. Authenticate is supposed to return the authenticated user object, so I woul ddo the former.

```
def authenticate(.....):
    try:
        return GalaxyUser.objects.get(username=username, password=password)
    except GalaxyUser.DoesNotExist:
        return None

user = authenticate(...)
user_id = user.id
```

Comment: galaxyuser is the name of the model and I am trying to retrieve id attribute from the galaxyuser model.

Comment: @user1881957, why would it be on the request object? Did you write some custom middleware? Is the `user` object returned by `authenticate` not the User you're looking for?

Comment: No I didn't. I thought it would be.

Comment: Storing plaintext passwords is a bad idea, but 2 things: you're returning a `QuerySet`. You should probably return a single object (via `get`). But seriously, plaintext passwords = bad idea. You should look into the default password mechanics to get an idea how to store / compare against secure passwords.

Comment: I am not storing the plain text passwords. The password is stored from Galaxy framework. I am decrypted the password inorder to compare. I want to get the id..Tell me how can I do that?

Comment: user1881957, I'm trying to tell you... please reread my comment. I will update answer with examples.

Comment: Please update your answer. Since get object returns only one result that won't work for me. There can be 100's of username and password in the galaxyuser table.

Comment: @user1881957. I did. That makes no sense. How can you authenticate a user/pass and return multiple users? How can you get a `user_id` from multiple users? If you mean `user_ids`, then sure `[user.id for user in authenticate(...)]`

Comment: Actually I want to return a single id. Would this return GalaxyUser.objects.get(username=username, password=password) authenticate users?

Comment: I want to get the id of the user who has entered the correct username and password.

Comment: @user1881957, yes. Wrap it in try/except as I've noted above in my post. And take heed of my warning about plaintext passwords. It's best to only store the result of a one way hash, so that it's impossible to even know their password.

Comment: I am not getting the user_id from user.id. However, authentication is working.

Comment: What are you getting from `user.id`? If you returned a single django object instance, then it's gotta be there. Is the type(user) == `GalaxyUser`?